# click() in a tag return href content

Tags: javascript

I want to simulate a user clicking on an `<a>` themselves. After grabbing the  and alerting the contents I was expecting [object], but instead I get the href content! I'm not using jQuery.

**Link**

```
<a href="javascript:showExplorerTab();" id="lnk_blend_explorer" onFocus="this.blur();">Blend</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
var o = document.getElementById("lnk_blend_explorer");
alert(o);
o.click();
```

Alert shows ... javascript:showExplorerTab(); ... and not ... [object]

Why is this happening?

Comment: which "contents" did you intend to alert?  Alerting an element directly is rarely useful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `<a href>` elements have a `toString()` method that returns their href attribute. Don't ask me why, that's just how it works.

Comment: Any way to override that behavior? Could you change the `toString()` in the prototype?

Comment: @xbonez: Maybe you can set `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.toString`?

Comment: some browsers (old IE?) really don't like it if you try to override properties of built-in types.